# How to keep wallet connected on page refresh using UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethereum, use-effect

I need to use the UseEffect to keep wallet connected if the page is refreshed this is my function.

```
const NavBar = ({ accounts, setAccounts }) => {
  const isConnected = Boolean(accounts[0]);

  async function connectAccount() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      setAccounts(accounts);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You will need to use `sessionStiorge` to save the data between refreshes

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which function fetch wallet(account) settings so I thought `connectAccount()` is that function.

maybe something like this one will help:

```
import {useMemo, useEffect} from 'react'

const NavBar = ({ accounts, setAccounts }) => {
const isConnected = useMemo(() => Boolean(accounts[0]), [accounts])

useEffect(() => {
  async function connectAccount() {
    if (window.ethereum) {
      const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({
        method: "eth_requestAccounts",
      });
      setAccounts(accounts);
    }
  }
}, [])
```